# How do I add authentication to a POST request on an implementation of hook_menu?

Tags: 7, users, javascript, ajax

I have a list of lesson plans, sorted by category. Underneath each category, I have a link called "Add new lesson/category/root term".

[image]

I would like it so that when the user clicks on "Add new category" or "Add new root term", they are prompted with a message box to get the name of the new term to add. Then, that message box will make an ajax call to **mysite.com/add-new-term**, with the name of the new term as a POST argument.

I know how to make an HTTP POST request using `jQuery.post()`. I know how to implement `hook_menu()` to enable requests to **mysite.com/add-new-term**. And I know how to use PHP's superglobal array `$_POST` to get the data from the request.

BUT, I don't know how to add user authentication to the request.

How can I ensure that only logged-in admins can make these requests? I don't want just *any random person on the web* to be able to create new terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is actually really easy.

You can [get the current user's roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232513/how-to-get-the-currently-logged-in-users-role-in-drupal-7) with:

```
global $user;
$roles = $user->roles;
```

That returns an associative array with the roles as values. Getting the values is trivial with [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
if (in_array("Teacher", $user->roles)) {
  // allow the post request to have effect
}
else {
  // don't go through with the request; return an error
}
```

Because the module is called during the lifecycle of the Drupal structure, you have access to the whole environment.